# Visualize the output of Trace in a tree structure

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The output of `Trace[expr]` can be nicely represented as a tree, I guess. 
Here is an example trace.

```
x = 5;
Trace[Mod[(3 + x)^2, x - 1]]

(* {{{{x,5},3+5,8},8^2,64},{{x,5},5-1,4},Mod[64,4],0} *)
```

How can I make a tree graph from this list?

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5527117/695132).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows a graphical tree of the expression.

```
HoldForm[{{{{x, 5}, 3 + 5, 8}, 8^2, 64}, {{x, 5}, 5 - 1, 4}, 
   Mod[64, 4], 0}] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Taking and running with image_doctor's example, you can get a representation without "HoldForm" visible like this:

```
Unevaluated @ Unevaluated[
 {{{{x, 5}, 3 + 5, 8}, 8^2, 64}, {{x, 5}, 5 - 1, 4}, Mod[64, 4], 0}
] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[See these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723277/618728) for some valuable thoughts about this method.

Comment: Could you please summarize the content of those comments?

Comment: @R.M you want me to summarize Leonid?  I don't think that is within my capabilities. :^)